Is an MDI like interface possible with sub nested breadcrumb trail?
In playing around with the various MarmeLab react-admin demos, it seems it's heavily dependent on the browser back button.  An eventual goal for our application is to host it within a bootstrap like shell app hosted in Chromium so there will not be any url bar or browser navigation back/fwd buttons or even new browser tabs.
The ecommerce demo doesn't seem that user friendly.  Looks great but awkward to use. Sure I can click around a lot, but then I loose my place and I have to use the browser backbutton.  For example, create customer doesn't have a cancel button to go back to the prior results.  Then I started filling out the new customer, then I clicked the Orders menu and nothing told me I was about to loose my changes, it just went to orders.  I can't work on more than one thing at a time unless I go out of my way to open multiple browser tabs.

Is there a way that when I click a menu item on the left, that it render that menu's content inside that main first window content area in a new tab, NOT a browser tab, but instead an html tab. If the user clicks another menu option, another html tab is rendered in the same window to show the new content. For example how apps like Visual Code, etc show new files in new tabs, instead of new instances of Visual Code. Similar to an MDI app but without the minimize, maximize, etc

Then inside that tab, render any additional "navigation" actions as breadcrumb trail inside that tab.  For example, in the ECommerce demo, one clicks the orders menu. So now a tab control would appear in the main content area of that page and the tab title would be "Orders" and the list would be displayed in that tab.  Now the user clicks an order # in the orders column and now at the top of that tab, the current contents, the list, are hidden, and at the top a breadcrumb appears that looks something like "Search -> Order: HW631U" and the contents of the order are now displayed. Somewhere in that breacrumb bar I would display my own back button to go back one step in the breadcrumb or the user could click search to jump directly back to that step.



That's some interesting feedback there, thanks! While react-admin does not have an MDI, it does have a Breadcrumb component (part of the Enterprise Edition, though). It also offers features such as EditInDialogButton, ReferenceOneInput, or ReferenceManyInput, allowing to edit more than one resource in one place.

Let me add that while react-admin doesn't have an MDI, it has all the building blocks to let you build it easily, while taking advantage of all its other capabilities.

Would be nice if they could create an example app that showcases the above scenario then!
